# Formula for Translation of Row Major to Column Major?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I have a UI control that displays data back in a series of tiles that are in column major format like so:

```
0  5  10
1  6  11
2  7  12
3  8  13
4  9  14
```

My datasource, a single array of values, gives me the position of where the items should appear like so:

```
0  1  2
3  4  5
6  7  8
9  10 11
12 13 14
```

The number of rows are static, with a variable number of columns.  The control will give me an index and I must find the appropriate data object for it.  I therefore need a formula for converting that column major index to a row index so that I can fetch the appropriate item.

I had created a formula that is able to do this, but is only valid for a dataset whose count is a perfect square.  **How can I do this with imperfect squares, for example, 5x60 matrices (300 items)?**

There is a method for doing this in a series of loops, building a 'map' so to speak of what translation needs to be made:

```
for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j) {
         int index = j * width + i;
         output[i * height + j] = input[index];
    }
}
```

I do not wish to keep this map in memory, however, because the number of items could potentially become very high, therefore, an algorithmic approach is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int rowmajorindexfromcolumnmajorindex(int columnmajorindex, int width, int height) {
    int row = columnmajorindex % height;
    int column = columnmajorindex / height;
    return row * width + column;
}

int columnmajorindexfromrowmajorindex(int rowmajorindex, int width, int height) {
    return rowmajorindexfromcolumnmajorindex(rowmajorindex, height, width);
}
```